# Select rows with all longitudinal measurements

Tags: r, subset, longitudinal

I have a longitudinal dataset with ID, Wave (Wave1-4), and Score. Here's sample data with the same structure. The length of the original data is around 2000, with 500 participants total, put in long form.

```
   ID   Wave Score
 1 1001 1    28
 2 1001 2    27 
 3 1001 3    28
 4 1001 4    26
 5 1002 1    30
 6 1002 3    30
 7 1003 1    30
 8 1003 2    30
 9 1003 3    29
 10 1003 4   28
 11 1004 1   22
 12 1005 1   20
 13 1005 2   18
 14 1006 1   22
 15 1006 2   23
 16 1006 3   25
 17 1006 4   19
```

I would like to select the 'ID's with all four measurements of 'Score' available. In other words, I want to select rows of the participants with 'Score' available for all 4 waves.
  I've been trying to select rows with 'ID's that have data in all 'Wave's. My tryout so far has been based on this idea: if a participant has all four measurements, the ID will appear in the data four times. 
 That's why I tried to count the number of IDs,

```
table(data$id) == 4
```

and although it showed me the number of each ID appearing in the data, I cannot select the corresponding rows.

```
all.data <- subset(data, subset=table(data$id) == 4)
```

Because the length of the original data is different, being in long form. "Length of logical index must be 1 or 2637, not 828" I would need a long-form data for further analysis, so I wish not to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like your `table()` approach.

```
> table(d$ID) == 4

 1001  1002  1003  1004  1005  1006 
 TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

The interesting IDs are in the `names()` though. So to get your code to work you could extract the IDs like so

```
subs <- names(which(table(d$ID) == 4))
```

and get your desired subset using `%in%`.

```
all.data <- subset(d, subset=d$ID %in% subs)
```

***Result***

```
> all.data
     ID Wave Score
1  1001    1    28
2  1001    2    27
3  1001    3    28
4  1001    4    26
7  1003    1    30
8  1003    2    30
9  1003    3    29
10 1003    4    28
14 1006    1    22
15 1006    2    23
16 1006    3    25
17 1006    4    19
```

(*BTW:* Always make sure with `?<name>` that you do not define any existing function names as object names, this will save you a lot of trouble. In your case type `?data` in a fresh session before loading the object.)

***Data***

```
> dput(d)
structure(list(ID = c(1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 1002L, 
1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1004L, 1005L, 1005L, 1006L, 1006L, 
1006L, 1006L), Wave = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Score = c(28L, 27L, 28L, 26L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 29L, 28L, 22L, 20L, 18L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 19L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df[as.logical(with(df, ave(Wave, ID, FUN = function(x) length(x) == 4))), ]

     ID Wave Score
1  1001    1    28
2  1001    2    27
3  1001    3    28
4  1001    4    26
7  1003    1    30
8  1003    2    30
9  1003    3    29
10 1003    4    28
14 1006    1    22
15 1006    2    23
16 1006    3    25
17 1006    4    19
```

Or if you want to keep your basic idea, a slight modification of @jay.sf code:

```
df[df$ID %in% names(which(table(df$ID) == 4)), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of feeding `table(data$ID)`, try with

```
ID %in% names(table(data$ID)[table(data$ID)==4])
```

As the `table` gives you the number of occurrences for each `ID` (named vector)

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick `data.table` answer.

```
  library(data.table)
  dt <- structure(list(ID = c(1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1003, 
  1003, 1003, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1005, 1006, 1006, 1006, 1006), 
Wave = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 
4), Score = c(28, 27, 28, 26, 30, 30, 30, 30, 29, 28, 22, 
20, 18, 22, 23, 25, 19)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

dt[ , .(Score, N = uniqueN(.SD)) , by = list(ID), .SDcols = c("Wave")][N == 4,]

 >   ID Score N
 1: 1001    28 4
 2: 1001    27 4
 3: 1001    28 4
 4: 1001    26 4
 5: 1003    30 4
 6: 1003    30 4
 7: 1003    29 4
 8: 1003    28 4
 9: 1006    22 4
10: 1006    23 4
11: 1006    25 4
12: 1006    19 4
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here are two `data.table` solutions. Both identify those `ID`s for which `Wave` has values 1 to 4. One approach uses subsetting, the other one is joining.

#### Subsetting

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ID %in% dt[ , which(uniqueN(Wave) == 4L), by = ID]$ID]
```

> ```
>       ID Wave Score
>  1: 1001    1    28
>  2: 1001    2    27
>  3: 1001    3    28
>  4: 1001    4    26
>  5: 1003    1    30
>  6: 1003    2    30
>  7: 1003    3    29
>  8: 1003    4    28
>  9: 1006    1    22
> 10: 1006    2    23
> 11: 1006    3    25
> 12: 1006    4    19
> ```

#### Joining

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .N, .(ID, Wave)][, .N, ID][N == 4L, .(ID)], on = "ID"]
```

which returns the same result.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
fread("
rn ID   Wave Score
 1 1001 1    28
 2 1001 2    27 
 3 1001 3    28
 4 1001 4    26
 5 1002 1    30
 6 1002 3    30
 7 1003 1    30
 8 1003 2    30
 9 1003 3    29
 10 1003 4   28
 11 1004 1   22
 12 1005 1   20
 13 1005 2   18
 14 1006 1   22
 15 1006 2   23
 16 1006 3   25
 17 1006 4   19", drop = 1L)
```